# If proven that all Collatz sequences attain bounded values, is it also proven that all sequences end up below the number you start from?

Tags: nt.number-theory, collatz-conjecture

I was researching upon the Collatz conjecture, and I was reading all the research work done by mathematicians including Terry Tao's. I had read that before Terry Tao's research it was proven that almost all Collatz sequences eventually end up below the number you start from. Is it like other sequences which are exceptions are the ones that may grow infinitely?
If proven that all Collatz orbits attain bounded values (hypothetical example), can the statement above be proven for all orbits?

Comment: If all directed orbits (except through $1$, as you presumably meant to say) had a value below the initial value, then Collatz's conjecture would follow by infinite descent.  So, in other words, you are asking if bounded orbits imply the Collatz conjecture, which I think is not known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not follow. Nothing in that work rules out that there might even be infinitely many distinct cycles from the Collatz function, all spread out a lot. So even if you had that sort of boundedness claim it would not follow.

Comment: I had worked on the boundedness proof therefore I wanted to know.

Comment: @AreenRath Speaking more generally, this may be a fun problem, but it isn't likely to be a productive line of thinking. Most mathematicians do not concentrate all their work on big unsolved problems, or if they do, they do so in ways where the problems connect to easily approachable small chunks that can be bitten off, and where not a lot of people have spent time thinking about that part of the problem.